# How is this beautiful function obtained? $2^s 3^{\frac{s+1}{2}} \pi\; {}_2{F}_1\left(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{s+1}{2};1;1-\frac{K^2}{12}\right)$

Tags: definite-integrals, hypergeometric-function, maple

From this integral (where $K$ and $s$ are constants):
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} {\left(K^2 {\mathrm{sin}}^2 \;t+12\;{\mathrm{cos}}^2 \;t\right)}^{\frac{s+1}{2}} \mathrm{dt}=$$

This beautiful result is obtained:
$$2^s\;3^{\frac{s+1}{2}}\;\pi\; _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{s+1}{2};1;1-\frac{K^2}{12}\right)$$

How was that? I know, it's a hypergeometric function, but I can't figure out how it is obtained.
I'd appreciate any help (perhaps how to obtain it with MAPLE). Thanks in advance!

Comment: $2^s3^{(s+1)/2}$ there is certainly $\frac12(12^{s/2})$, at least, which points to part of the answer: pull out a factor of $12^{s+1/2}$ from the integrand to change it to $(\frac{K^2}{12}\sin^2t+1)^{(s+1)/2}$.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, definitely. But I'd still be stuck in the integral XD

Comment: I've found here https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AppellHypergeometricFunction.html a result for the general integral $\int{\left(a+b\;\mathrm{sin}x+c\;\mathrm{cos}x\right)^n\mathrm{dx}}$, but I'm not very versed in hypergeometric functions.

Comment: Take $u = \sin^2 t$, you'll get [Euler's integral representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric#Integral_formulas) of ${_2 F_1}$.

Comment: Thanks. If I take that, my integral will transform (I think) into this: $\frac{1}{2}\;12^{\frac{s+1}{2}}\int^1_0{\left[u(1-u)\right]^{-\frac{1}{2}}\left[\left(\frac{K^2}{12}-1\right)u+1\right]^{\frac{s+1}{2}}} du$. From that, I can't relate it with the Euler's integral representation, as you suggest (sorry, I'm an Engineer).

Comment: Correct, then if you take $a = -(s + 1)/2$, $b = 1/2$, $c = 1$, $z = 1 - K^2/12$, you'll get
$$u^{b - 1} (1 - u)^{c - b - 1} (1 - z u)^{-a} =
u^{-1/2} (1 - u)^{-1/2} (1 - (1 - K^2/12) u)^{(s + 1)/2}.$$

Comment: Brilliant! I got it! Thanks a lot!